# Taking the (n+1)st power

Tags: calculus

I've got trouble to find a rule that enables me to take the (n+1)st. power. If this rule exists can I use it in general?
This is my example, I was looking at the e-number proof and one of the steps says this:
$$
e^{1/(n+1)}\leq 1+ \frac{1}{n}
$$
Now, the author of the article allows us to take the (n+1)st power and the equation will look like this
$$
e\leq (1/n+1)^{n+1}
$$
Why this is allowed?

Comment: Because for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have$$a\le b\iff a^{n+1}\le b^{n+1}$$

Comment: The idea here is that
$$
0 < a\leq b \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad a^k \leq b^k
$$
for $k>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: In the initial (pre-edited) version of the question, $1/n+1$ was meant as $1/(n+1)$ in the exponent (of $e$) and elsewhere meant as $(1/n)+1$.  It helps to be aware that parentheses are sometimes necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $$x^{n}$$ is monotonic for $x\ge 0.$ Thus, if you have two nonnegative numbers $a$ and $b$ with $$a\le b,$$ it follows that $$a^n \le b^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look for a graph of $f(x)=x^{n+1}$. You will see that, since the function is always increasing in value as $x$ gets bigger, for any $a,b>0$, $a<b$ and $a^{n+1} \leq b^{n+1}$ are equivalent (either both true or both false)

Because of this, the first inequality being true implies the second inequality being true as well (and vice-versa)

Also note that $(e^\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} = e$

Answer (score 0):

This results from very basic properties of inequalities:

> If $a<b$ and $c>0$, then $ac<bc$. If $c<0$, then $ac>bc$.

It follows by a trivial induction the following rule:

> If $\;0\le a <b$, then for any $n>0$, $0\le a^n<b^n$.
>
> If $\;a <b\le 0$ and $n>0$, then
>
> - If $n$ is odd, $\;a^n<b^n\le 0$.
> - If $n$ is even, $\;a^n>b^n\ge 0$.